# Azure Database On Unity

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-sql-database, vuforia

I'm developing an AR app with Unity and `Vuforia` . And `onclick` of button i need to send data to azure `sql` and fetch data from it . How to do this with unity ?

Comment: Are you working with Azure SQL Database or Azure Database for MySQL?

Comment: Its Azure SQL Database ,

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/AppServices/blob/master/README.md) demo project on Git Hub. From that demo project you can try below method to connect:

```
    public class AzureConnect : MonoBehaviour {
    private MobileServiceClient _client;
    private MobileServiceTable<Score> _table;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _client = new MobileServiceClient("https://myService.azurewebsites.net"); // <- add your app url here.
        _table = _client.GetTable<Score>("Score");
        ReadItems();
    }
    private void ReadItems()
    {
        StartCoroutine(_table.Read<Score>(OnReadItemsCompleted));
    }

    private void OnReadItemsCompleted(IRestResponse<Score[]> response)
    {
        if (!response.IsError)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnReadCompleted: " + response.Url + " data: " + response.Content);//content shows the content of the table properly
            Score[] items = response.Data;//Data is always null
            Debug.Log("Todo items count: " + items.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Read Error Status:" + response.StatusCode + " Url: " + response.Url);
        }
    }
}
```